# Group by string before a "-" / Creating new columns based on multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

For starters sorry for the horrible title. I couldn't come up with a good one.

Background: I have a Sales data table that produces this output:

```
+-------------------+---------+-------------+--+
|    AccountName    | OrderID | ShipToState |  |
+-------------------+---------+-------------+--+
| Apple-Houston     |       1 | TX          |  |
| Apple-Austin      |       2 | CA          |  |
| Apple-Austin      |       3 | NY          |  |
| Apple-Austin      |       4 | CA          |  |
| Apple-Austin      |       5 | NY          |  |
| Apple-San Antonio |       6 | NY          |  |
| Microsoft-NYC     |       7 | TX          |  |
| Microsoft-Chicago |       8 | NY          |  |
+-------------------+---------+-------------+--+
```

This shows sales we have had and where they have shipped to.

My desired end result is to:

1. Group Accounts with the same name before the "-" together.
2. Show which Grouped Account have had sales in each of the following states: TX, CA, NY, IL

There desired output should look like this:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+
| AccountName | CA  | TX  | NY  | IL |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+
| Apple       | YES | YES | YES | NO |
| Microsoft   | NO  | YES | YES | NO |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

For the first part, I did this:

`Select SUBSTRING(sd.[Account Name], 1, CHARINDEX('-',sd.[Account Name]+'-') - 1)
From Sales_Data sd`

This works in general, but i'm not sure how it'll work when bringing in part two of this question.

As for the second part, I'm genuinely at a loss. I tried this:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(sd.[Account Name], 1, CHARINDEX('-',sd.[Account Name]+'-') - 1),
  CASE WHEN sd.[Ship to State] = 'CA' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS CA,
  CASE WHEN sd.[Ship to State] = 'TX' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TX,
  CASE WHEN sd.[Ship to State] = 'NY' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS NY,
  CASE WHEN sd.[Ship to State] = 'IL' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS IL
  FROM SALES_DATA sd
```

but it returns results that look like this:

```
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+----+
| Account Name | CA  | TX  | NY  | IL |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+----+
| Apple        | no  | yes | no  | no |
| Apple        | yes | no  | no  | no |
| Apple        | no  | no  | yes | no |
| Apple        | yes | no  | no  | no |
| Apple        | no  | no  | yes | no |
| Apple        | no  | no  | yes | no |
| Microsoft    | no  | yes | no  | no |
| Microsoft    | no  | no  | yes | no |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but if it is I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below SQL.

```
SELECT AccountName,
(case when CA > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as CA,
(case when TX > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as TX, 
(case when NY > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as NY, 
(case when IL > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as IL
FROM
(
select SUBSTRING(AccountName, 1, CHARINDEX('-', AccountName +'-') - 1) as AccountName, OrderID, ShipToState
FROM SALES_DATA) as sd
PIVOT
(
 count(OrderID)
 FOR ShipToState IN ([CA],[TX],[NY],[IL])
) AS PivotTable;
```